# org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property update found for type User

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I work with small Spring boot form handler project. The `entity` class `User` is provided below,

```
@Entity
public class User {

    // form:hidden - hidden value
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer id;

    // form:input - textbox
    @Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(30)", nullable = false)
    String name;

    // form:input - textbox
    @Column(name = "email", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50)", nullable = false)
    String email;

    // form:textarea - textarea
    @Column(name = "address", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)", nullable = true)
    String address;

    // form:input - password
    @Column(name = "password", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(20)", nullable = false)
    String password;

    // form:input - password
    String confirmPassword;

    // form:checkbox - single checkbox
    @Column(name = "newsletter", nullable = true)
    boolean newsletter;

    // form:checkboxes - multiple checkboxes
//    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(500)", nullable = false)
    @ElementCollection
    List<String> framework;

    // form:radiobutton - radio button
    @Column(name = "sex", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(1)", nullable = true)
    String sex;

    // form:radiobuttons - radio button
    @Column(name = "number", nullable = true)
    Integer number;

    // form:select - form:option - dropdown - single select
    @Column(name = "", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(10)", nullable = true)
    String country;

    // form:select - multiple=true - dropdown - multiple select
//    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(500)", nullable = true)
    @ElementCollection
    List<String> skill;

    //Check if this is for New of Update
    public boolean isNew() {
        return (this.id == null);
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getConfirmPassword() {
        return confirmPassword;
    }

    public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
    }

    public boolean isNewsletter() {
        return newsletter;
    }

    public void setNewsletter(boolean newsletter) {
        this.newsletter = newsletter;
    }

    public List<String> getFramework() {
        return framework;
    }

    public void setFramework(List<String> framework) {
        this.framework = framework;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public List<String> getSkill() {
        return skill;
    }

    public void setSkill(List<String> skill) {
        this.skill = skill;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof User)) return false;

        User user = (User) o;

        if (isNewsletter() != user.isNewsletter()) return false;
        if (!getId().equals(user.getId())) return false;
        if (!getName().equals(user.getName())) return false;
        if (!getEmail().equals(user.getEmail())) return false;
        if (getAddress() != null ? !getAddress().equals(user.getAddress()) : user.getAddress() != null) return false;
        if (!getPassword().equals(user.getPassword())) return false;
        if (getConfirmPassword() != null ? !getConfirmPassword().equals(user.getConfirmPassword()) : user.getConfirmPassword() != null)
            return false;
        if (!getFramework().equals(user.getFramework())) return false;
        if (getSex() != null ? !getSex().equals(user.getSex()) : user.getSex() != null) return false;
        if (getNumber() != null ? !getNumber().equals(user.getNumber()) : user.getNumber() != null) return false;
        if (getCountry() != null ? !getCountry().equals(user.getCountry()) : user.getCountry() != null) return false;
        return getSkill() != null ? getSkill().equals(user.getSkill()) : user.getSkill() == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        int result = getId().hashCode();

        result = 31 * result + getName().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + getEmail().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + (getAddress() != null ? getAddress().hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + getPassword().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + (getConfirmPassword() != null ? getConfirmPassword().hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (isNewsletter() ? 1 : 0);
        result = 31 * result + getFramework().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + (getSex() != null ? getSex().hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (getNumber() != null ? getNumber().hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (getCountry() != null ? getCountry().hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (getSkill() != null ? getSkill().hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

The `UserRepository` class is provided,

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    User findById(Integer id);

    List<User> findAll();

    void update(User user);

//    void delete(Integer id);
}
```

In the `service` directory, the interface and the implementation is also provided,

```
public interface UserService {

    User findById(Integer id);

    List<User> findAll();

    void save(User user);

    void update(User user);

//    void delete(int id);
}
```

The implementation of the class is provided below,

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public User findById(Integer id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public List<User> findAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void save(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public void update(User user) {
        userRepository.update(user);
    }

//    public void delete(int id) {
//        userRepository.delete(id);
//    }
}
```

When I run the program, I get the error,

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property update found for type User!
```

Obviously, this comes from the `update` method. I use `HSQL` database. How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method called as `update` in Spring data CRUD repository it is equivalent to save.

`save` method takes care of persisting new entity if it is new or merge the existing entity.

Have a look at `SimpleJpaRepository` class.Here is the snippet :

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }

}
```

In case, if you want to write native queries on top of method use `@Query`:

```
@Query('<<UPDATE QUERY>>')
update(..)
```

Few suggestions to the code shared:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {


}
```

Remove all the methods as methods defined are already available through the [`CrudRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/):

```
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends Repository<T, ID> {

    <S extends T> S save(S entity); 

    T findOne(ID primaryKey);       

    Iterable<T> findAll();          

    Long count();                   

    void delete(T entity);          

    boolean exists(ID primaryKey);  

    // … more functionality omitted.
}
```

Comment: We need an annotation in the top of the interface though, 

`@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends Repository<T, ID> { ... }`

Comment: @AAA Not required as part of the newer releases.

Comment: @AAA try with spring boot 1.5.6.RELEASE or 1.5.7.RELEASE. Exactly not sure from which release.